# На какую нагрузку рассчитан QML? Детонация памяти и зависание от перегрузок

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

День добрый. Стояла задача разработать интерфейс для устройства, в котором гигантское количество параметров. Для каждого параметра создаётся соответствующее поле ввода. На входе есть древо групп, в которые распределены эти параметры. Это древо передаётся в QML и на его основе динамически создаётся древовидный интерфейс с вкладками, в которых располагаются поля для ввода. Изначально все вкладки закрыты и у пользователя нет возможности открыть их все.

На каждую группу параметров требуется примерно, В СРЕДНЕМ, 2 Мб памяти(это было выяснено во время отладки приложения с параллельным просмотром количества потребляемой ОЗУ в диспетчере задач).

На основе одного древа параметров генерируется окно интерфейса на 200 Мб. Количество параметров колеблется в районе тысячи. Т.е. для каждого параметра динамически(ЕДИНОЖДЫ) создаётся виждет(label + textEdit + checkBox). Программа должна загрузить 10 таких окон, а значит отожрёт около 2 Гб.

Проблема заключается в том, что программа выдерживает не более двух-трёх таких деревьев. Если загрузить больше, то обязательно вылетит SIGSEGV или программа зависнет при попытке открыть сгенерированное окно.(При чём, из четырёх загруженных окон, первое открывается без проблем, второе с ощутимой задержкой, а третье 100% черевато вылетом программы с зависанием.) Важным моментом является то, что программа спокойно выдерживает 10-15 деревьев по меньше, где количество параметров не превышает сотни.

Сразу примем на веру:
Утечек памяти нету, так как все объекты создаются динамически только один раз.

Суть вопроса:
Рассчитан ли QML на такие нагрузки, когда, единовременно, в нём загружено более тысячи графических объектов? 
Возможно у вас был опыт работы в QML с большим количеством объектов, поделитесь, если не сложно.

Comment: Насчёт рассчитан/не рассчитан не знаю, но может быть не надо для каждого параметра создавать элементы управления ? А просто при переходе в очередную вкладку использовать уже существующие,изменив у них подписи ? Например,сделайте панель с деревом(иерархией) (как в файловой системе), по которому можно передвигаться, и при выборе определённого элемента из иерархии отображайте только те параметры, которые можно ввести в этом элементе. Не обязательно же жёстко связывать элемент управления/ввода с каждым параметром.

Comment: "генерируется окно интерфейса на 200 Мб" это что за интерфейс такой на 200 метров? О_о

Comment: QML и графические Фреймворки в целом не расчитаны на такие нагрузки. QML в плане эффективности вообще не заморачивается. Подразумевается, что в один момент времени будут обрабатываться только объекты непосредственно отображаемые на экране в данный момент. Не надо делать тысячи виджетов. Сделайте их пару десятков или сколько влезет на экран и обновляйте данные в них при прокрутке и переходах.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, интерфейс, в котором 1000 параметров, на каждый из которых полагается по 3 графических виджета. + прочие объекты qml, не видимые на экране. По количеству полей у каждого объекта в всё более-менее сходится.

Comment: Я не говорю, что мой подход правильный. Да и сам адекватно понимаю что 200 мб это слишком много. Так что ищу новые решения.

Comment: Мне тут подсказывают, что в случае "дофига одинаковых компонентов" есть смысл вместо динамической генерации один раз всего массива посмотреть в сторону ListModel. Она позволяет не держать все объекты в памяти разом, а автоматом грузит только то, что в пределах области просмотра, и выгружает ненужное.